# Dynamically changing widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to change the limits of widgets on a tkinter GUI and need to dynamically change them once the GUI is open and running.

For example, a scale widget's lower and upper limit needs to change once the GUI is running.

I have tried the various `destroy()` and `forget()` methods to delete the widget and replace the original one but I feel like this is not the best way to do it.

I have also tried just creating another instance of the widget in the hopes the original disappears but unsurprisingly this did not work either (I had to give it a go to find out what would happen).

Is there a better way of doing this that I'm missing or should I `forget()` said widget and create a new instance of the widget?

```
    import tkinter
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.ttk import *

    def moveStuff():
        setres=5 
        mySlider=tkinter.Scale(root,from_=-45,to=45,resolution=setRes,
                         orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL,bd=0)
        #mySlider.place(x=10,y=50)

    setres=1

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("Open file window")
    root.geometry("200x200")

    otherButton=tkinter.Button(root,text="MOVE STUFF",command=moveStuff)
    otherButton.pack()

    mySlider=tkinter.Scale(root,from_=-90,to=90,resolution=setres,
                     orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL,bd=0)
    mySlider.place(x=10,y=100)
```

I would ideally like the scale widget to change its lower and upper limit when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your imports are all over the place. And also why don't you simply modify the configuration of your existing slider, instead of creating a new one?

```
import tkinter as tk

def moveStuff():
    mySlider.config(from_=-45, to=45) #change slider max and min

setres=1

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Open file window")
root.geometry("200x200")

otherButton=tk.Button(root,text="MOVE STUFF",command=moveStuff)
otherButton.pack()

mySlider=tk.Scale(root,from_=-90,to=90,resolution=setres,
                 orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,bd=0)
mySlider.place(x=10,y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do I not simply modify the configuration of the existing slider? Because I did not know you could do that. So thank you for telling me.

Comment: As for why my imports are a mess, because I am new to python and am teaching myself, I have no idea what I'm doing nor do I study computer science so a lot of this is new to me. Can you suggest what I should me importing instead, What have I imported incorrectly? @Henry Yik

Comment: All widgets in tkinter can be configured after creation as long as you keep a good reference of the widget objects. For imports, it is usually not recommended to use wild card import *. The usual way is to `import tkinter as tk`, and then `from tkinter import ttk` if required so you know clearly which module you are importing the widgets from.

Comment: This may be a stupid question but what does `import *` do? What is the problem with it? I knew there was a problem with it but I could not understand what?

Comment: Because you won't know what exactly are being imported, and it is particularly bad for tkinter since there are widgets like `tk.Button` and `ttk.Button`. If you use wild card import, you wouldn't know which one you are using. For a better explanation, search the site for **import * bad practice.**

Comment: So my understanding is, we are importing libraries which contain the tkinter widgets for example and by using `from tkinter import *` we are allowing instances of the widgets to be created by saying `newLabel = Label(...)` but instead you should write `import tkinter as tk` and then create an instance of a widget by typing `newLabel = tk.Label(...)`. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. This can prevent ambiguity, especially when your code gets complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is very much appreciated!